# keras CAE Error when checking target: expected conv2d_7 to have shape (252, 252, 3) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I set the convolutional layer and the pooling layer, then deconvolute and de-pool, the input shape of 256 * 256 * 3 images, but finally there is a shape error:

```
def build_auto_encode_model(shape=(256,256,3)):

    input_img = Input(shape=shape)  

    x = Convolution2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)  
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)  
    x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)  
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)  
    x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)  
    encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)  

    x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)  
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)  
    x = Convolution2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)  
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)  
    x = Convolution2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)  
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)  
    decoded = Convolution2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)  

    encoder = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=encoded)

    autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=decoded)  
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy') 
    return encoder, autoencoder

def train_auto_encode_model(encoder_model_path="./data/encoder.h5"):
    X = np.load("data/train.npy")
    X_train = X[int(round(X.shape[0] * 0.2)):, :]
    X_test = X[0:int(round(X.shape[0] * 0.2)), :]

    encoder, autoencoder = build_auto_encode_model()
    autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, validation_data=(X_test, X_test))
    encoder.save(encoder_model_path)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Error when checking target: expected conv2d_7 to have shape (252, 252, 3) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)
```

[image: data shape]

Error trace-back:

[image: error]

Comment: Good that you didn't post the code as an image, but why the error message should be in an image?

Comment: Thank you, the first upload, I will pay attention next time-_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‌By using `autoencoder.summary()` you would see that the output shape of the last Conv2D layer is `(None, 252, 252, 3)`; so the labels of shape `(256,256,3)` are not compatible. The cause of this problem is that you have forgotten to set the `padding` argument of previous Conv2D layer. By setting it to `'same'` this problem would resolve:

```
x = Convolution2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
```